# Is it possible to add videos to YouTube's offline playlist via an external app?

Tags: ios, youtube-api

I am developing an iOS application where I would like to provide users with specific YouTube links. Instead of downloading these videos, I want to utilize YouTube's offline feature and allow users to save these videos to their YouTube offline playlist for later viewing.

Is there any way or API provided by YouTube to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like Google provides an API for this, here is an [endpoint](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/insert). And keep in mind that user should authorize in your app with his Google account.